# When is a mySQL permission error not a permission error

Tags: mysql, mac-osx

So I've been going sort-of crazy for the past few days.  I've got a mac, OSX 10.6.4, and I HAD mySQL running on it.  At some point after the 10.6.4 update, mySQL stopped working.  I got an error telling me that mySQL couldn't find the mysql.sock file.

I've uninstalled/reinstalled mySQL a couple of times and nothing is helping.  if I run the mysqld coommand in my bin directory I get a bunch of errors that lead me to believe there was a permission error on the data directory, but data is owned by mysql...so I'm lost.  I'm not really a DB guy, I just need one on my machine for connecting to wordpress and things like that.

This is everything out of local.err

```
101007 21:47:34 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql-5.5.6-rc-osx10.6-x86_64/data
error: Found option without preceding group in config file: /etc/my.cnf at line: 2
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
101007 21:47:34 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql-5.5.6-rc-osx10.6-x86_64/data/JoeC.local.pid ended
101007 21:48:20 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
101007 21:48:20 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
101007 21:48:20 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
InnoDB: The first specified data file ./ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
101007 21:48:20  InnoDB: Setting file ./ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
101007 21:48:20  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
101007 21:48:20  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
InnoDB: 127 rollback segment(s) active.
InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
101007 21:48:21 InnoDB 1.1.2 started; log sequence number 0
101007 21:48:21 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Permission denied
101007 21:48:21 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/mysql/mysql.sock ?
101007 21:48:21 [ERROR] Aborting

101007 21:48:21  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
```

help?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the mysql process is currently running

```
ps -ef | grep mysqld
```

Does that give you any output?  If it is not the just the grep command itself then the process is still running.

Next check if mysql has any files open

```
lsof | grep mysql
```

Does that give you any output?  This is a list of files open by mysql.  It may explain why it is hanging around for.

Have you restarted your machine?  (You shouldn't need to - but you may have a process hanging around)

Answer (score 1):

1.) Either MySQL is running
or
2.) Your not running MySQL as a user with correct permissons
    try sudo first before the command.. so running it as root..
    My mac asks for a password - whereby it can run it as the correct user

Hope this helps :D